# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Can you help me find this limit:$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$

I tried to use
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} = \ln\left(\exp\left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} \right)\right)$$ but it didn't work out so well.

This problem came up when I was trying to find the radius of convergence of the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left[\dfrac{2^{n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}\right]^p.x^n$$
Thanks!

(Anyway I omitted the exponential $p$ in the limit because it just a constant).

(*Edited. Is there any others way instead of using Stirling approximation(1) or the Center Binomial Coefficient(2)? I just stated learning Analysis and this limit is only a part of the finding the radius of convergence problems,though. It take way too long and hard to prove (1) and (2)). Sorry for not  ask clearly the first time.

Comment: You can use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) that $\binom{2n}n\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ to see what the limit is if you realize that $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}=(2n+1)\binom{2n}n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n$ is the sequence in question then we have $$\frac {x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac {2n+2}{2n+3}=1-\frac{1}{2n+3}$$ and therefore $$\log\frac {x_{n+1}}{x_n}<-\frac{1}{2n+3}$$ On summing such inequalities for $n=1,2,\dots,n$ we get $$\log\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_1}<-\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac {1}{2m+3}$$ The RHS diverges to $-\infty $ and therefore so does the LHS. It should now be clear that $x_n\to 0$.

---

Use of Stirling formula can be avoided in most cases and one should try to apply the standard tests for convergence.

Comment: I still can't see what is your $x_n$. Can you help me clear that? Thanks?

Comment: @aDmaL: well, as stated in this answer, $x_n$ is the expression under limit ie $x_n=(2^{2n}(n!)^2)/(2n+1)!$ and you are supposed to find limit of $x_n$ as $n\to \infty $.

Comment: The downvote does not appear to be related to closure and deletion of the question (as it happens with answers to low quality questions). Let me know if there is something which can be improved or fixed.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)(2n)!}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}\sqrt{\pi n}}{(2n+1)4^n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{(2n+1)}=0\\
\end{align*}
using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties).

Answer (score 2):

My first approach would be to begin with Stirling's approximation:

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n} \implies (2n+1)! = \sqrt{2\pi(2n+1)} \frac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}{e^{2n+1}}$$

Using this, you get that your limit - call it $L$ - is equivalent to

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n} \cdot 2\pi n \cdot \frac{n^{2n}}{e^{2n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi(2n+1)}} \cdot \frac{e^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}$$

A bit messier, but note:

- The $e$ terms can cancel to give you $e$
- The $\pi$ and $\sqrt{\pi}$ cancel to give the latter
- You can group the powers of $2$ and $n$, and then the pair together themselves
- The constants not dependent on $n$ can be brought outside the limit

With these in mind and some minor algebraic manipulations, you get

$$L = e \sqrt{\frac \pi 2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{2n}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

Noting that $2n = 2n+1-1$, you can simplify the parenthetical even more:

$$L = e \sqrt{\frac \pi 2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

I imagine it is sufficiently obvious that the limit is zero as a result. If not, let's continue from here. Show that the limit of each factor exists, and then you have

$$L = e \sqrt{\frac \pi 2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

With a redefining of $m=2n+1$ in the left-hand limit, you find the limit expression to be $(1 - 1/m)^m$, which is well-known to approach $1/e$. The right-hand limit is more obviously $0$. Thus,

$$L = e \sqrt{\frac \pi 2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} = e \sqrt{\frac \pi 2} \cdot \frac 1 e \cdot 0 = 0$$

---

Alternatively, per Brian's comment, we get a slicker solution. Notice,

$$\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

which means, per a simplification he also notes and $4^n = 2^{2n}$,

$$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{1}{(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{(2n+1) 2^{2n}}$$

This in turn gives us that

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{2n} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{(2n+1) 2^{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2n+1} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks! Really detailed, but any other ways to find this limit without Stirling formula or Center Binomial Coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

You have:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}{(1)(2)(3)\cdots(2n)(2n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left((2)(4)(6)\cdots(2n)\right)^2}{(1)(2)(3)\cdots(2n)(2n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2)(4)(6)\cdots(2n)}{(1)(3)\cdots(2n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac23\frac45\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\exp\left(\ln(1-1/3)+\ln(1-1/5)+\cdots+\ln(1-1/(2n+1))\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Note that
$$\ln(1-1/3)+\ln(1-1/5)+\cdots+\ln(1-1/(2n+1))<-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\cdots-\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
because $\ln(1-x)<-x$. And the right side is negative harmonic, so its partial sums are arbitrarily large negative. Therefore so are the partial sums from the left side. Therefore the $\exp$ above will be given arbitrarily large negative numbers. And therefore the limit is $0$.

Comment: Can you explain more how you can imply the second equal sign? (At line 2).

Comment: And like you said. $\ln(1-x) < -x$, so should the inequality be $\ln(1-1/3)+\ln(1-1/5)+\cdots+\ln(1-1/(2n+1))<\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}$ instead of what you have written?

Comment: For that second equals sign: $2^nn!$ is $\overbrace{2\cdot2\cdot\cdots\cdot2}^{n\text{ copies}} \overbrace{\cdot1\cdot2\cdot\cdots\cdot n}^{n \text{ factors}}$. There is one "$2$" for each factor from the factorial. Pair them up and you have $2\cdot4\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)$.

Comment: I don't follow your second comment. Yes, $\ln(1-x)<-x$. So for example, let $x$ be $1/5$. Then $\ln(1-1/5)<-1/5$. A negative one fifth belongs there, not positive.

Comment: This is essentially the argument used in my answer, but I can clearly see that it is written independently (perhaps without the knowledge that a similar answer existed).

Comment: Thank a lot. The way you express your answer is much more easier to understand with my current knowledge! But @ParamanandSingh answer with the same idea first, though.

Comment: That's fine. I wouldn't say they are the same answer though. The latter half of each is the same. But the other answer begins by directly examining ratios of successive factors, and this answer directly examines the sum terms. But it's fine, really.

Answer (score 0):

By induction easy to show that:
$$\binom{2n+1}{n}>\frac{2^n\left(1+\sqrt[n]{n+1}\right)^n}{n+1}.$$
Thus, $$ \dfrac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{2^{2n}n!(n+1)!}{(n+1)(2n+1)!}<\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt[n]{n+1}}\right)^n\rightarrow0$$